# (Hibernate-Search-lucene) How to index a field in another object(B) whose primary key is present as foreign key in object A

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I have two classes :

### Class A : (to be searched)

```
@Entity
@Indexed
Class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    protected Long id;


    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    protected B b; // foreign key
}
```

### Class B :

```
@Entity
Class B {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;


    private String fieldToBeIndexed; // ** I want to index this field **

}
```

As I am working on a project and there search is done only for class A :

eg : FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, A);

I want to search A by passing the value of B's field (fieldToBeIndexed) in the search box. How can I achieve this. How can I index B's field(fieldToBeIndexed) so that A can be searched based on B's field(fieldToBeIndexed).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `@IndexEmbedded`:

```java
@Entity
@Indexed
Class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    protected Long id;


    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @IndexedEmbedded
    protected B b; // foreign key
}
```

I assume you are using Hibernate Search 5, so here's the link to the docs on IndexedEmbedded for this version https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-mapping-associated

Comment: This. Also, you might want to model the inverse side of the association in `B` and annotate it with `@ContainedIn`, so that `A` gets reindexed when `B` changes.